# Не работает паттерн

Tags: javascript

```js
var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*$");
console.log(strongRegex.test("123456Gg!"));
console.log(strongRegex.test("123456Gg"));
```

Есть вот такой паттерн. Все работает. Ниже прикрепил код где я беру паттерн из тега в input

```js
var test = document.getElementById("pass2");

var pattern = test.getAttribute("pattern");
const re = new RegExp(pattern);


console.log(re.test(test.value));
```

```html
<input pattern="^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*$" type="password" value="123456Gg!" id="pass2" >
```

В данном случае паттерн возвращает false. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В данном случае паттерн возвращает false. Почему так происходит?

Потому что строки будущего регулярного выражения не равны

```js
var test = document.getElementById("pass2");

var pattern = test.getAttribute("pattern");
console.log(pattern === "^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*$");


const re = new RegExp(pattern);


console.log(re.test(test.value));
```

```html
<input pattern="^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*$" type="password" value="123456Gg!" id="pass2" >
```

Равны они будут вот так (без одного обратного слеша `\`)

```js
var test = document.getElementById("pass2");

var pattern = test.getAttribute("pattern");
console.log(pattern === "^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*$");

const re = new RegExp(pattern);


console.log(re.test(test.value));
```

```html
<input pattern="^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W).*$" type="password" value="123456Gg!" id="pass2" >
```